# Counting number of events per day & their duration

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have time-series on a minute level where I log certain events, for simplification here I use binary classification, is there an event or not. And I want to get some daily stats on it.
I tried to explain what I have and what I want to get in the figure below
[image]

So in summary I would like to detect all events (1) with their duration.
What would be the easiest way of doing this in Python, Pandas?

Here is extract from the dataframe

```
Time    
2020-01-27 09:26:00     0
2020-01-27 09:28:00     0
2020-01-27 09:30:00     0
2020-01-27 09:32:00     0
2020-01-27 09:34:00     0
2020-01-27 09:36:00     0
2020-01-27 09:38:00     0
2020-01-27 09:40:00     0
2020-01-27 09:42:00     0
2020-01-27 09:44:00     0
2020-01-27 09:46:00     0
2020-01-27 09:48:00     1
2020-01-27 09:50:00     1
2020-01-27 09:52:00     1
2020-01-27 09:54:00     1
2020-01-27 09:56:00     1
2020-01-27 09:58:00     1
2020-01-27 10:00:00     1
2020-01-27 10:02:00     1
2020-01-27 10:04:00     1
2020-01-27 10:06:00     1
2020-01-27 10:08:00     1
2020-01-27 10:10:00     1
2020-01-27 10:12:00     1
2020-01-27 10:14:00     1
2020-01-27 10:16:00     1
2020-01-27 10:18:00     1
2020-01-27 10:20:00     1
2020-01-27 10:22:00     1
2020-01-27 10:24:00     1
```

Comment: Is data stored in a pandas dataframe? or in a list?

Comment: In pandas dataframe

Comment: could you post an extract?

Comment: I added extract, but I'm not sure is it meaningful here since the dataset is too long to put here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it by myself. Here is how:

I calculated the difference between current and previous timestep and based on that I've counted number of occurrences of an event and calculated time difference between start (1) and end of an event (-1).

```
Sessions['Diff']=Sessions['Event'].diff()

begin = Sessions.loc[Sessions['Diff'] == 1].index
cutoffs = Sessions.loc[Sessions['Diff'] == -1].index

idx = cutoffs.searchsorted(begin)
mask = idx < len(cutoffs)
idx = idx[mask]
begin = begin[mask]
end = cutoffs[idx]

result = pd.DataFrame({'begin':begin, 'end':end})

result['dT']=result['end']-result['begin']
result['dT']=result['dT'].dt.total_seconds().div(60)
result=result.set_index('begin',drop=False)
result=result.rename(columns={'begin':'sessions','dT':'avg_dT'})
result['tot_dT']=result['avg_dT']

Sessions_daily=result.resample('D').apply({'sessions':'count','avg_dT':'mean','tot_dT':'sum'})
```

Where Sessions is a data frame of time-series (minute sampling) is there event (1) or not (0)

This resulted in

```
    sessions    avg_dT  tot_dT
begin           
2020-01-03  5   31.200000   156.0
2020-01-04  0   NaN     0.0
2020-01-05  0   NaN     0.0
2020-01-06  0   NaN     0.0
2020-01-07  9   39.333333   354.0
2020-01-08  8   38.000000   304.0
2020-01-09  8   33.000000   264.0
2020-01-10  8   39.250000   314.0
```